# upload image from android UI to php server side api

Tags: php, android

i got two questions.

1) i want to upload image into php server and the front end will be android. and i want all processing to be done by php api like checking image and name extension and even error checking .

All the tutorials that i surfed has done in such way that most of the processing is done in android and only for storing uses php api. so any suggestion which supports above requirement will be of great help.

2) $_FILES["fileContents"]["type"] this line in php api is directly used with android uploadimage . i know that it initates file browse option but how to pass parameter value ['fileContents'] from android code.

thanks

Comment: 1. why don't you just follow those tutorials you studied and just remove the processing on the client side and add whatever processing you need on the server side? Since you don't say what that is nothing more can be said here...

Comment: 2. that variable `$_FILES["fileContents"]["type"]` has nothing to do with "initializing file browsing". It indicates the files content type to the php script on the server side to simplify processing the file.